# How is Illustrator overprint preview calculated?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, overprint

I'm trying to plan an art print, and I need to use overprinting to reach the colors I'm after. For the most part, Illustrator's multiply blend mode seems to function the same as the overprint preview. But not always. Different colors all seem to work differently.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

[image]

After further studying this, it looks like the literal Cyan and Magenta colors work as expected, but color blends don't. Here's an example of two boxes that are close to cyan and magenta, and two that are actually 100% those colors:

[image]

Comment: Do you actually have Overprint Preview turned on? Is *only* the cyan set to overprint at the top? Only the red set to overprint in the middle? [I can't get the same results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoInV.jpg) you show in your sample. Is your **Document Color Mode** set to **CMYK**? Is something a spot color?

Comment: @PickleRick agreed, i too can not replicate this.

Comment: This question ins potentially good, but the first option does not make sense, there is no way cyan and red produces green.

Comment: @Rafael, Try it. It actually behaves the way the OP describes. You're correct that it doesn't make sense, yet it is the way it works.

Comment: @LateralTerminal perhaps, but it doesn't answer why it looks this way in the preview.

Comment: I think this question could be actually dealt  if it could be answered. But as it is I can not preplicat ethis problem no matter i do my overprint behaves exactly the same no matter the order. SO either this is a big of somekind or a regression in some verison of illustrator. To do that youd need to know what version and os you use. I can not replicate this on a win7 machine using CC (22.1), or CS5 (15.0.2) nor CS6 (16.0.2). It works correct no matter how i put it. So my guess is this is a bug

Answer (score 1):

Overprinting only works on spot colors and (pure) C, M, Y, or K. If you change the color type to spot, you will see the results you expected.

Caveat: using spot swatches in conjunction with transparency effects like multiply or <100% opacity levels may cause unexpected output results. The overprinting attribute doesn't cause these issues.